# Syntax error due to wrong Indentation in Python

Tags: python

I am getting this error while compiling.I know why it's happening but couldn't find the solution as i am a newbie . This problem occurs at line
34 and after else .This is second edit

File "check.py", line 34

```
else:
   ^
```

IndentationError: expected an indented block

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from wand.image import Image
from PIL import Image as Img
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import glob

 # put all resume in a directory (inp_dir)

inp_dir = '/home/sameer/Downloads/resumes/resume_v7/'

# expect all txt files in this dir (out_dir)

out_dir = './pdf_img3/'

# filenames in all_resumes folder

filename1 = [x for x in os.listdir(inp_dir)]
for f in filename1:
    try:
        with Image(filename=inp_dir + f, resolution=200) as img:

        # keep good quality

            img.compression_quality = 80
            f = f.split('.')[0]
            img.save(filename='%s%s.jpg' % (out_dir, f))


    except Exception as err:
        print err
    else:

        pathsave = []
        try:
            #print 'there must be 2 pages in the pdf'
            list_im = glob.glob('%s/%s*.jpg' % (out_dir, f))
            list_im.sort()  # sort the file before joining it
            imgs = [Img.open(i) for i in list_im]

            # now lets Combine several images vertically with Python

            min_shape = sorted([(np.sum(i.size), i.size) for i in
                           imgs])[0][1]
            imgs_comb = np.vstack(np.asarray(i.resize(min_shape))
                              for i in imgs)

             # for horizontally  change the vstack to hstack

            imgs_comb = Img.fromarray(imgs_comb)
            pathsave = '%s%s-f.jpg' % (out_dir, f)

            # now save the image

            imgs_comb.save(pathsave)

            # and then remove all temp image

            for i in list_im:
               os.remove(i)
        except Exception as err:
            exit()
```

Comment: It's nothing to do with indentation. You don't have any functions in your code, so what exactly do you expect to return from?

Comment: You have a `return`, but do you actually have a function defined for this code you showed?

Comment: This isn't actually an indentation issue. What do you think `return` does?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `return` inside `except` block ?

Comment: Ya i have but i didn't put it here

Comment: If you've got a function in your code you should [edit] your question and add it. We can't give you good advice with only partial information.

Comment: For the problem you are experiencing, you need to show a more exact representation of your code to help indicate where your problem lies.

Comment: hey changed the question a bit ,please help

Comment: This can't actually be reproduced with the code shown. I can make some guesses, based on the post editing history, about what really happened; but it's better to just point at the guide for fixing this sort of problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to return False from the try block then you need to have the try block inside of a function. The TestFunction would test if the image is good and return True or False. If the TestFunction returns True then continue on to the next step, else print error message and break or exit.